# Why is Leobolt searching for Finis?

Tags: lost-song

After the turning point in *Lost Song*, we learn that we saw two different "Time Circles" the whole time:

1. Leobolt falls in love with Finis and is killed by her
2. Rin searching for Finis

In Time Circle 2, Leobolt never met Finis before. Why is he searching for her? As far as I remember, he only knows he has to save her.

Finis also reacts surprised that Leobolt appears infront of her to save her and also notes to Leobolt that she is going to kill him eventually. As far as I remember at least.

This felt really off.